# Compute the expectation of this stochastic process

Tags: expectation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following stochastic process

$X_t = (1-t)\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{1-s} dW_s$ and let 
$ \bar{X}_t = \begin{cases} X_t &\mbox{if } 0\leq t <1 \\
0 & \mbox{if } t=1 \end{cases} $

Compute $E[\bar{X}_t]$

My attempt: $E[(1-t)\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{1-s} dW_s] = (1-t)E[\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{1-s} dW_s] = 0 $

since $E[\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{1-s} dW_s] = 0 $

I'm unsure whether my working is correct here or if im missing something in computing its expectations.

Comment: Something seems off about this formulation, particularly, how does $\bar{X}$ depend on $t$? It shows up in a piece-wise definition but... did you mean $\bar{X}_t$?

Comment: oh yes sorry that was suppose to be $\bar{X}_t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, as phrased. If $t = 1$ then $E[\bar{X}_t] = E[0] = 0$. If $t < 1$, then recognize $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 - s} dW_s$ as a martingale and thus $E[\bar{X}_t] = E[\bar{X}_0] = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, i wasnt sure as the marks given to this part didn't seem proportional to the amount of work done

Comment: Please accept the answer.